# How to build url hierarchy for project composed with decoupled Backbone.js apps?

Tags: javascript, rest, web-applications, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I like the way how Django do subj. It allows to define 'local' url inside apps, and then include them in project-level root url config and define prefixes for them. 
Like - local urls are: `that/<id>`, `this/<slug>/` and global prefix for entire app - `verygoodapp/`.

In Backbone.js this can be done through `root` parameter for `History.start()` function.

But in this case I will need to do 
`History.start({root: arbitraryUrlPrefixForThatAppPassedAsArgFromAboveLocalSpace})` 

in every applciation. 
Is it ok? How js gurus do that?

upd
I wrote that and realized that probably I need just write:

```
function(urlRoot) {
  var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      urlRoot + 'content/:slug': 'openArticle'
    },
    ...
  });
}
```

And do `History.start()` just once in global project space. Not tested yet.

upd2
Now I think that [reverse resolution of urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) like in Django would also be cool to implement with Backbone. AFAIK Backbone Routers do register their routes in some centralized  internal facility.

Comment: Do you need to modify this route dynamically after the page has loaded, or can you, through javascript, get it once and set it as the root parameter?

Comment: I think in 99% cases it will be the second option, but who knows, maybe first once will become trendy and everybody will do sites with dynamic urls :)